# Segue between multiple detail views when selecting from tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview, swift

Ok, I haven't been able to find a definitive answer to this. I'm on Xcode 6 working with Swift and a UISplitView. I have multiple detail views in storyboard and I want to be able to replace my detail view with another when selecting from a tableview. In Xcode 5, I was able to drag multiple segues from my prototype cell and use performSegueWithIdentifier. In Xcode 6, I can only have one segue coming from my prototype cell.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "UISplitView".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One type of cell, one segue. This seems to be a logical and useful system constraint.

One solution is to just create more cell types with different cell identifiers.

Alternatively, if you have another way to determine which segue to use, draw all segues from the view controller instead of the cell. You can attach the necessary row object information in the `sender` object when calling the segue from the cell selection method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many segues  as u want  from viewcontroller and give each seuge an different segue Identifier in IB, and the call each with performSegueWithIdentifer method